# How to wait for a Kinesis Stream creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I need to create a Kinesis Stream programatically and then start performing operations on it. Create Stream is an async operation. What is the best way to establish when the stream is ready?

Is it polling for the a stream status and waiting for a response with StreamStatus `ACTIVE`?

Comment: I think that is only option for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can poll, but otherwise if you have the option you can stream to an intermediate destination such as `CloudWatch`, and then once the stream is active it will begin consuming those events.